# Microsoft Script Editor (MSE) download

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

A while back i saw a link on here which let you download an installer for MSE. I should have copied it down but i didnt. Now i really need it.

I know that it comes with office 2002, but i cant install that right now. If someone has a link please share it.

I think its easy to find if you know the file name, which i dont.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? MSE is so old that it's been replaced several times since 2002.

Comment: i am trying to debug javascript on IE6 on a P3-800mhz

Comment: @mkoryak: you have my sympathy!

Comment: @Shog9: you should feel sorry for me. i am working(!) on a weekend debugging js in IE6 without proper tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the long lost link. it was the crappy script debugger after all:

http://www.filewatcher.com/m/scd10en.exe.669648.0.0.html

Comment: that link was for the microsoft script debugger, which is different than the microsoft script editor that comes with Office. I'm still looking for a link to MSE for the same reasons as the OP. :)

Comment: allan: i somewhatly resolved this years ago and blogged about it here: http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2008/08/debug-javascript-in-ie.html in a nutshell, use the debugger that comes with visual stupido